# Find out process active handle (lock) on special file using WINAPI

Tags: windows, go, winapi

I want to use this [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pldmgg/misc-powershell/master/MyFunctions/PowerShellCore_Compatible/Get-FileLockProcess.ps1) as resource to write same as in Go for Windows by using Windows API (reset manager)

So far my code is

```
Rstrtmgr := syscall.NewLazyDLL("Rstrtmgr.dll")
RmStartSession := Rstrtmgr.NewProc("RmStartSession")
RmRegisterResources := Rstrtmgr.NewProc("RmRegisterResources")
RmGetList := Rstrtmgr.NewProc("RmGetList")

var dwSession uint32 = 0
var szSessionKey = Utils.RandString(32)
ret, _, callErr := RmStartSession.Call(
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&dwSession)),
    uintptr(0),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(szSessionKey))))


var rgsFileNames = unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(szPath))
ret, _, callErr = RmRegisterResources.Call(
    uintptr(dwSession),
    uintptr(1),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&rgsFileNames)),
    uintptr(0),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nil)),
    uintptr(0),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nil)))


var nProcInfoNeeded uint32 = 0
var nProcInfo  uint32 = 10
var lpdwRebootReasons uint32 = 0

type RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS struct {
    dwProcessId         uint32
    ProcessStartTime    windows.Filetime
}

type ApplicationType struct {
    RmUnknownApp   uint32
    RmMainWindow   uint32
    RmOtherWindow  uint32
    RmService      uint32
    RmExplorer     uint32
    RmConsole      uint32
    RmCritical     uint32
}

type RM_PROCESS_INFO struct{
    RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS    RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
    strAppName           string
    strServiceShortName  string
    RM_APP_TYPE          ApplicationType
    AppStatus            uint32
    TSSessionId          uint32
    bRestartable         bool
}

var _RM_PROCESS_INFO [10]RM_PROCESS_INFO
ret, _, callErr = RmGetList.Call(
    uintptr(dwSession),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&nProcInfoNeeded)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&nProcInfo)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&_RM_PROCESS_INFO)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpdwRebootReasons)),
    )
_ = ret
_ = callErr
```

but I have error on RmGetList

my Goal is get the PID of that process lock my file by path

I edit my code. Please review it

- example in [c++](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=8283)

Comment: I created [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/xynwizTQSOX) while looking into the problem. It also includes error output but it doesn't look like a "normal panic".

Comment: @xarantolus thanks to hear some one care about it, but how we can solve?

Comment: @xarantolus maybe args 3 of RmRegisterResources should be string array not string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/nf-restartmanager-rmstartsession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RmRegisterResources` need a rgsFileName**s** which means the pointer of the File Name string(s) you can pass the array of the string(s), or just pass the address of the filename string if you only have to work on one special file.

```
var rgsFileNames = unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(szPath));
ret, _, callErr = syscall.Syscall9(RmRegisterResources,
    7,
    uintptr(dwSession),
    uintptr(1),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&rgsFileNames)),
    uintptr(0),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nil)),
    uintptr(0),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nil)),
    0,
    0)
```

Comment: Hi, did this solve your issue?, please remember to mark if this did answer you, or you can also add an answer which is available for you.

Comment: Thanks sir, solve my problem stage 1. What about next stage? @drake-wu-msft